# XML Schema Validation in VBA with muliple namespaces

Tags: xml, vba, validation, schema

I’m trying to validate an .XML file against an .XSD file with MSXML 6.0 DOM but on executing the code I’m getting an error. Tomalak had an answer to a similar question a couple of years ago (stackoverflow.com/questions/11708492). I would like to know: How can I add TWO namespaces to the following code snippet (objSchemaCache.Add ...)

```
Sub XSD_Validation()

    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objSchemaCache As New XMLSchemaCache60
    Dim objErr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError

    objSchemaCache.Add "http://somewhere.com/root", LoadXmlFile("I:\Test.xsd")

    Set xmlDoc = LoadXmlFile("I:\Test.xml")
    Set xmlDoc.Schemas = objSchemaCache

    Set objErr = xmlDoc.Validate()
    If objErr.errorCode = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No errors found"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error parser: " & objErr.errorCode & "; " & objErr.reason
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765387(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per the following. These won't work in this case but are simply to show you how you add and where you add. I haven't gone through the rest of your code.

```
Sub XSD_Validation()

    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objSchemaCache As New XMLSchemaCache60
    Dim objErr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError

 '   objSchemaCache.Add "http://somewhere.com/root", LoadXmlFile("I:\Test.xsd")
    Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespace
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:content=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"""
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:other=""http://www.other.org/other/other"""
    Set xmlDoc = xmlDoc.LoadXML("I:\Test.xml")
    Set xmlDoc.Schemas = objSchemaCache

    Set objErr = xmlDoc.Validate()
    If objErr.errorCode = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No errors found"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error parser: " & objErr.errorCode & "; " & objErr.reason
    End If
End Sub
```